# After authenticating token (ACCESS GRANTED), doesn't redirect to Callback URL

Tags: ios, oauth, withings

I'm implementing **OAuth 1.0** in an **iOS app** using [simple-oauth1](https://github.com/Christian-Hansen/simple-oauth1) project. I use **Withings API** so I modified a little bit from simple-oauth1 (like consumer oauth key, secret key, callback URL...). And I inserted:

> NSLog(request.URL.absoluteString); like the following code(It's in
> OAuth1Controller.m)

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)
request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{   
    if (_delegateHandler) {
    NSString *urlWithoutQueryString = [request.URL.absoluteString componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"][0];
    NSLog(request.URL.absoluteString);
    if ([urlWithoutQueryString rangeOfString:OAUTH_CALLBACK].location != NSNotFound)
    {
```

With that code,

1. I tap the `OAuth login` button then webview shows login page.
2. I enter ID/password.
3. Webview shows account allow page. I tap "Allow" button. (NSLog shows http://oauth.withings.com/account/authorize?acceptDelegation=true&oauth_consumer_key=blahblah&oauth_nonce=blahblah&oauth_signature=blahblah&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=blahblah&oauth_token=blahblah&oauth_version=1.0&userid=blahblah)

After above process, webview shows "ACCESS GRANTED" page with oauth_token= blahblah, oauth_verifier=blahblah. But it doesn't redirect to Callback url, it stays at the "ACCESS GRANTED"page.

I've been doing this for about 2 weeks but I cannot find the answer why is this happening.

Comment: What did you use for your AUTH_URL, REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, API_URL, etc? I can't even get the login page to show up in the simple-oauth1 sample project. Got it working just fine with Fitbit...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (using php). The problem seems to be that you must provide a url callback at the request token step (first step, not the authorization).

[Withings API not redirecting to my callback url (PHP / OAuth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320618/withings-api-not-redirecting-to-my-callback-url-php-oauth/18323964#18323964)